# Re-registration of WCF endpoint thows "already exists" even after an abort

Tags: c#, wcf, exception, fault

I'm facing a strange problem with WCF endpoint manager highly available windows service using Azure Service fabric, which provides callbacks when the service becomes active.

Everytime the service becomes active, we register the WCF endpoints using:

A)

```
serviceHost = CreateServiceHost(IWcfContractInstance)
serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(...)
serviceHost.Open()
```

Whenever the service is deactivated (note: process does not go down in this case)

B)

```
serviceHost.Close()
```

They both are under lock and there is no synchronization issue here. The problem is that A fails , saying that the endpoint is already registered. 
StackTrace:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The ChannelDispatcher at 'net.tcp://localhost:[PORT]/IWcfContract '"ContractName"' is unable to open its IChannelListener. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: 
A registration already exists for URI 'net.tcp://localhost:[PORT]/IWcfContract'.
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.UriPrefixTable`1.RegisterUri(Uri uri; HostNameComparisonMode hostNameComparisonMode; TItem item)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionOrientedTransportManager`1.Register(TransportChannelListener channelListener)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportManager.Open(TransportChannelListener channelListener)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportManagerContainer.Open(SelectTransportManagersCallback selectTransportManagerCallback)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportChannelListener.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionOrientedTransportChannelListener.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TcpChannelListener`2.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableChannelListenerBase`1.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
```

The strange thing is that B) also fails and throws CommunicationObjectFaultedException. So the question is, calling a Close on a faulted session should dispose off the resoureces, so that when we go ahead and register this endpoint again, it should just work.

Am I missing something here ?

Comment: You can't call close on a faulted channel - that will throw an exception.  you have to call `.Abort()`.